# How do I put old e-mails in a new client, if they're not downloading from IMAP?

Tags: email, imap

**Preamable:**

On OS X 10.15.7 I am tidying up both my old mails and my mail processes.

I want to change from Mail.app to Unibox.

**Situation:**

After configuring Unibox (I can send! I can recieve!) no new mails enter the application!
I am currently checking the mails with spike and via webmail, I know they are there…

**Wish**

I want my new mails to pop up into Unibox. What could be wrong in my IMAP setup to prevent this? If the same settings are used in another app and that works fine, it suggests something is wrong elsewhere, right?

**Question**

What could be wrong, where do I start looking?

What would be the workaround to move old mails from Mail.app to Unibox (if possible)

P.s. Unibox have so far not responded to my support request of 10+ days ago